I cannot use "multipart/form-data" as Content-Type while using Body/form-data
When I send a request with Body/form-data, POSTMAN use Content-Type = "application/json; charset=utf-8" as a bad request.

I tried change the Headers setting manually, but it doesn't work.
This api works when I use raw/JSON and x-www-form-urlencoded.
You are up to date! Postman v10.24.18 is the latest version.
I would like to know how to make POSTMAN send that request with multipart/form-data so that api can work in body/form-data.

what exactly do you mean with "cannot use" - you wrote about a "bad request", this would indicate a result of HTTP status code 400, but the screenshot shows HTTP status code 500, which is "internal server error" and indicates a problem in the implementation of the API. So I think it's probably not a problem of Postman.

thanks for point out the error code.
I figure out that I use wrong KEY in body.
To upload a photo,
I was usring "file" as the key, which is the variable used in controller.
I should use "image" as the key, which I set the name for multer middleware.
router.put('/users/:id', authenticated, upload.single('image'), apiUserController.putUser)

So if you solved your question yourself, you should either add all relevant information to the question, and create an answer, and accept it - or you remove the question as it cannot be answered because it lacks essential information. Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is meant to also help others that have the same problem as you at a later time.

Using multer allowed me to use form-data upload the image. Happy coding!
